# Basic vertical center in CSS behaving strangely on floated element

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

So i've come to live by these 3 CSS rules that *almost* always vertically center any block level element:

```
  .vertically-center {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY( -50% );
  }
```

It works often. But in the case of this particular layout I'm building it is pushing the elements too high ( partially off the screen ) and I don't know why.

This is how the webpage looks *before* adding my `vertically-center` class to my `portrait-container` div:

[image]

And this code snippet is how it appears after adding the `vertically-center` class to the `portrait-container` div:

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.vertically-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
main {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
}
.portrait-container {
  float: left;
}
img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.about-container {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<main class="clearfix">
  <div class="portrait-container vertically-center">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Eb5sRZr.jpg" alt="Portrait of John Lesko">
  </div>

  <div class="about-container">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <p>
      Hi, I'm John Lesko! This is my art portfolio where I share all 
      of my favorite work. When I'm not creating things, I enjoy excercising,
      playing video games, drinking good Kool Aid, and more.
      
      <br><br> If you'd like to follow me on Twitter, my username is 
      <a href="http://twitter.com">@jletsgo</a>.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

I just want the image container to be vertically-centered regardless of the height of it's parent. Help? Inspecting elements gave me no insights.

**Edit: Just to show how this has always worked for me in the past. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kyjt8ze/4/. Why does it work for me there and not here?**

Related question: [What does top: 50%; actually do on relatively positioned elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310189/what-does-top-50-actually-do-on-relatively-positioned-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> Edit: Just to show how this has always worked for me in the past. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kyjt8ze/4/. Why does it work for me there and not here?

The black circle is the only element there in the Fiddle, there's no obstructions. In the code you are having trouble with, you have many elements either in the way or wrapped around other elements trapping them. Your ruleset will work if you start stripping away the layers. Or you can just add a property and change another property as per Snippet 1.

---

**One important note** a `relative` element is actually occupying the original spot, so if given a `left:40px` it *appears* to be moved 40px to the left, but in reality it still occupies the space 40px to the right of where it appears to be. So `relative` elements are not really in a flow different from `static` elements. Therefore they are affected by and affect `static` layout, it's just not noticeable *normally* because they stack with `z-index`.

Snippet 2 is an interactive demo, I figured maybe that'll help explain things better.

---

The 3 CSS ruleset is a common way to vertically align elements, but it was originally `position: absolute` instead of `position:relative` and it had to be in another `position`ed element if I remember correctly.

**REFERENCE**

- [Specific Ruleset](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/centering-absolutely-positioned-elements-with-left-50-and-33-left-margin/#post-173005)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

**SOLUTION**

```
.vertically-center {
  /* Changed to absolute from relative */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
}
main {
  /* Added position: relative */
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
}
```

**SNIPPET 1**

```css
.vertically-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY( -50%);
}

body {}

main {
  padding-top: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.about {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<main class="clearfix">

  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Eb5sRZr.jpg" alt="Portrait of John Lesko" class="vertically-center">


  <article class="vertically-center about">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <p>
      Hi, I'm John Lesko! This is my art portfolio where I share all of my favorite work. When I'm not creating things, I enjoy excercising, playing video games, drinking good Kool Aid, and more.</p>

    <p>If you'd like to follow me on Twitter, my username is
      <a href="http://twitter.com">@jletsgo</a>.
    </p>
  </article>
</main>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```js
$('#b1').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('R S');
});

$('#b2').click(function() {
  $('#N1,#N2,#N3').toggleClass('N M');
});

$('input[id$="2"]').on('input', function() {
  var grp = "." + $(this).attr('class');
  var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  grp !== '.S' ? $('section' + grp).css('left', num + '%') : $('section.S').css('margin-left', num + '%');
});

$('input[id$="3"]').on('input', function() {
  var grp = "." + $(this).attr('class');
  var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  grp !== '.S' ? $('section' + grp).css('top', num + '%') : $('section.S').css('margin-top', num + '%');
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: scroll;
  font: 400 12px/1.2 Consolas;
}

section {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px dashed grey;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.R {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .3)
}

.A {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3)
}

.F {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3)
}

.S {
  position: static;
  background: rgba(122, 122, 0, .3)
}

.N {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
}

.M {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: yellow;
}

#R1 {
  left: 20%;
  top: 3%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#A1 {
  left: 42%;
  top: 44%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#F1 {
  right: 20%;
  top: 44%;
  z-index: 3;
}

#S1 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: -28%;
}

#N1 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 4;
}

input {
  width: 6ex;
  position: static !important;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='S'>
  <fieldset>
    <button id='b1'>Body Relative/Static</button>
    <button id='b2'>Nested Absolute/Relative</button>
    <br><br> RLeft
    <input id='R2' class='R' type='number' value='20'> RTop
    <input id='R3' class='R' type='number' value='3'> ALeft
    <input id='A2' class='A' type='number' value='44'> ATop
    <input id='A3' class='A' type='number' value='44'><br> FLeft
    <input id='F2' class='F' type='number' value='64'> FTop
    <input id='F3' class='F' type='number' value='44'> SLeft
    <input id='S2' class='S' type='number' value='0'> STop
    <input id='S3' class='S' type='number' value='-28'><br> NLeft
    <input id='N2' class='N' type='number' value='45'> NTop
    <input id='N3' class='N' type='number' value='45'>

  </fieldset>

  <section id='R1' class='R'>RELATIVE
    <section id='N1' class='N'>N<br>E<br>S<br>T<br>E<br>D</section>
  </section>
  <section id='A1' class='A'><br><br><br>ABSOLUTE</section>
  <section id='F1' class='F'><br><br>FIXED</section>
  <section id='S1' class='S'><br><br><br><br><br>STATIC</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Interesting, Thank you. Seems to work but I've never had to use `absolute` positioning or put this in other positioned elements before. Something there in my code is breaking my original way of doing it.

Comment: There's 50px of padding from the top?

Comment: Yeah, however when I remove the padding in chrome dev tools the layout is still broken.

Comment: As long as the parent is `position: relative`, if the child is `position: absolute` the child will be positioned relative to the parent as opposed to being positioned truly absolutely.

Comment: Yes, it's sorta of a misnomer. Here's a something from Paulie_D: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/centering-absolutely-positioned-elements-with-left-50-and-33-left-margin/#post-173005

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9kyjt8ze/4/ This is a basic example of the parent not being positioned but the effect still working. I wonder why?

Comment: Body is the only thing it can reference to. a 50% margin still translates to 50% of parent.

Comment: ... and a `relative` positioned element references itself so a translate of -50% is correct behavior. What is probably confusing you is that a `relative` element is referencing itself whilst an `absolute` positioned element will reference the closest positioned element. If that closest positioned element happens to be the parent that will allow you to control the `absolute` child accurately. Originally, you had it's parent (non-positioned), which wasn't the reference for the `relative` child.

Comment: In this situation it turned out to be the height of the containing elements causing this code to break. If you can't explicitly set the height of container elements then it appears you can't use the 3 line CSS trick as I've shown and you must get more creative as you've done here.

Comment: Actually, it's an old technique no creativity involved with using `relative` and `absolute` that way. If you use a set of defaults, you can avoid many problems like the one you just had. [`normalize.css`](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.css) addresses many of them, like in your situation, it already sets `html` and `body` to height and width to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS was not bad but I didn't get along with it. So here is another approach on how you could solve it, maybe it helps also. It will always center the image vertically and does not matter how much text the `box` on the right will have. The colored borders are just there to help show the visual effect of the box sizes.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.portrait-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.portrait-container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.portrait-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 80px); /* 50% from top minus half img height*/
  width: 150px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.portrait-container {
  border: solid 2px orange;
}

.portrait-container .about-container {
  border: solid 2px green;
  padding: 0 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;        /* this elements should be at least 150px away from left side */
  width: calc(100% - 150px); /* the max width this element should have to be placed */
                             /* next to the image is the total width(100%) - the image width  */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="portrait-container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Eb5sRZr.jpg" alt="Portrait of John Lesko">

    <div class="about-container">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <p>
        Hi, I'm John Lesko! This is my art portfolio where I share all 
        of my favorite work. When I'm not creating things, I enjoy excercising,
        playing video games, drinking good fruit punch, and more.

        <br><br> If you'd like to follow me on Twitter, my username is 
        <a href="http://twitter.com">@jletsgo</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<main>
  <div class="portrait-container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Eb5sRZr.jpg" alt="Portrait of John Lesko">

    <div class="about-container">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <p>
        Hi, I'm John Lesko! This is my art portfolio where I share all 
        of my favorite work. When I'm not creating things, I enjoy excercising,
        playing video games, drinking good fruit punch, and more.

        <br><br> If you'd like to follow me on Twitter, my username is 
        <a href="http://twitter.com">@jletsgo</a>.
      </p>
      <p>
        Hi, I'm John Lesko! This is my art portfolio where I share all 
        of my favorite work. When I'm not creating things, I enjoy excercising,
        playing video games, drinking good fruit punch, and more.

        <br><br> If you'd like to follow me on Twitter, my username is 
        <a href="http://twitter.com">@jletsgo</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `flexbox`with a lot less code. The below code will do the trick.

```
.clearfix {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.about-container {
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Check it out in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWYxrb