# What does top: 50%; actually do on relatively positioned elements?

Tags: html, css, position, vertical-alignment, centering

I've been using relatively positioned elements to center things vertically for a while. I never understood, though, why `position: relative; top: 50%;` doesn't vertically center the element, **or** at least center the top edge of the element in it's container div.

`position: relative` according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjusts the element's position, without changing layout

The  [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) keyword:

> specifies the amount the element is moved below its normal position.

And a [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) value on the `top` keyword:

> Is a percentage of the containing block's height

So a relatively positioned element with a value of `top: 50%` should be moved 50% of the containing blocks height downward, right? Doesn't this mean that the top edge of that element is exactly in the middle of the containing element?

Consider this snippet:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.child {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #444;
  border-top: 5px solid #f00;
}
.top-50-percent {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
}

.contract-and-expand {
  animation-name: contract-and-expand;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes contract-and-expand {
  50% {
    height: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* Just initial/basic CSS rules here to make this look better */
      
      @import url("https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css");

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        color: #aaa;
      }
      .center-vertically {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY( -50% );
      }
      p {
        position: absolute; /* Remove paragraphs from flow so they don't interfere */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center-vertically contract-and-expand">
      <p>Container Wrapper</p> <!-- Paragraphs are removed from the flow -->
      
      <div class="child top-50-percent">
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

From the snippet it looks like the top edge is centered. Is this always correct? there's this similar fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kyjt8ze/5/ when the height of the viewport is pulled up the top border of the child element no longer looks centered.

Comment: Did you bother to look at your earlier question?

Comment: That question led to this...It kind of makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I measured this with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) and 2 ( yellow ) vertical blocks the same exact size. It's an optical illusion. The top edge never actually gets off center in that fiddle. Also all of my assumptions appear correct: `top:50%` on relatively positioned elements moves the top border of that element down 50% of the container's height. The reason this doesn't perfectly vertically center the element is the *top edge* is the pivot point when using `top: 50%` on relatively positioned elements.

[image]